# Initialize vector <char> with int values

Tags: c++, vector, char, int, narrowing

I want to initialize this char vector with this ASCII codes:

```
vector <char> a = { 201, 187, 200, 188, 205, 186 };
```

and I get this syntax error in all of the 6 characters:

> Invalid narrowing convertion from "int" to "char": constant value does not fit in destination type

but when I initialize a single char variable, with the same ASCII codes:

```
char b = 201;
```

It works fine.

So I realized that in vectors, for some reason, char type can receive int values until 127. Starting 128 the syntax error appears.

This is different than in normal variables, when char type can receive any int values.

I tried declaring the vector as unsigned char, and the syntax error dissapears.

```
vector <unsigned char> a = { 201, 187, 200, 188, 205, 186 };
```

But still,

Why char type vectors cannot receive the same int data as char type variables?

I really would appreciate someone explaining me this behavior.

Comment: If it is a regular char you cannot go past 126. Did it work with unsigned chars?

Comment: so why "char b=201" works?

Comment: It gives you an overflow compiler error

Comment: my doubt is, why: char b=201; works, and why vector <char> b ={201}; doesnt. Why I get that error with vectors and no with normal variables.

Comment: What do you mean that `char b = 201` works? Because you don't get a compiler warning?

Comment: exactly. and I can cout the character assigned to 201 which is an special one.

Comment: Go to your compiler and after you do `char b=201`, you should add below that, `std::cout << "Char c equals 201? " << std::boolalpha << (c == 201) << std::endl;`, and see the output you get

Comment: Moreover, next time you compile your code, make sure to use the `-pedantic` flag. Using that flag will warn you of this overflow which you thought was normal

Comment: interesting. So I don't get the warning. And why if I am loosing data, I still get to print the ASCII code character that I was expecting?

Comment: The ASCII standard only defines characters in the range [0,127]. Anything higher is one of the many, many extensions to ASCII; confusingly, many of these go by “extended ASCII” even though none of them is an official extension. This doesn’t affect your program because as far as the C language is concerned, anything that fits into one byte can be stored in a `char` and it really doesn’t care that much about the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things going on.

1
The first is the default range of values for the `char` type, which is ***implementation defined***. In most major compilers the default is [-128,127]. (And, oddly, this is *not* the same as `signed char`, JSYK!)

Both MSVC and GCC provide options to treat `char` as signed or unsigned. You can do that to fix the problem globally.

Better, though, is not to assume `char` handles anything outside the range [0,127]. Use `signed char` or `unsigned char` to be specific.

2
The second is that you are using [brace initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), which requires that literal element values be checked for range fit.

For your examples:

```
std::vector <char> xs = { 201, 202 };  // compiler error

char x { 201 };  // compiler error

char x = 201;  // compiler warning
```

If you don’t have your compiler’s error level cranked up (and you should) then the compiler will silently ignore that warning and assign the value, even though it is technically invalid.

Comment: Thanks!! This really helped a lot. One last doubt. I understand that, if the compilers assigns the value despite the fact that in doesn't fit, I would be losing data. Why I am still getting the character I expected? (ASCII code =201) in this example.

Comment: @WalterS.Escobedo The compiler will wrap around to within the `char`s ranged (this isn’t guaranteed, but pretty much all compilers do that on conversion from an `int`). Thus, it assigns the value `-55`. That’s the same underlying byte as positive 201, and when you write it out it gets sent to the screen the same way.

Comment: Thanks Daniel H. This really helped a lot!.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to do that, because character literals are in single quotes only, and numbers (without suffixes) are ints.  You can add a L, LL, UL, ULL to make a literal long, long long, and unsigned versions, plus some other for floating points, etc., but no such suffix exists for chars.

However, if you have a C++11 or later compiler, you can write your own user-defined literal to help with this:

```
constexpr char operator "" _c(unsigned long long arg) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<char>(arg);
}

int f()
{
  std::vector <char> a = { 201_c, 187_c, 200_c, 188_c, 205_c, 186_c };
}
```

If this isn't an option or you just don't like it you could always write an ordinary function to do something similar:

```
constexpr char c(int arg) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<char>(arg);
}

int f()
{
  std::vector <char> a = { c(201), c(187), c(200), c(188), c(205), c(186) };
}
```

Comment: Did you just define a `_c` operator? Cool

Comment: @smac89 there is no need though

Comment: thanks for the reply, but im more interested in the behavior of char type. why  `char b=201` ;  works, and why `vector <char> b ={201};` doesn't?

Comment: This is not true. It is possible to convert an `int` to a `char` without a new operator or function (as you see by the fact that you can *write* the function). This also doesn’t avoid the issues with converting something out of range; your behavior is still implementation-defined. Finally, it doesn’t answer the question: it doesn’t say *why* `char b = 201` works but `char b{201}` and `std::vector<char> v = { 201 }` do not.

Comment: @WalterS.Escobedo That's because {201}, an unadorned numeric literal has type "int".  When you put it in a char, then you've changed the type.

Comment: @DanielH I didn't say it's not possible to convert without an operator or function; I said there is no way to write a literal numeric in source code with the type of 'char'.  Of course one could cast the int to a char, but that is only necessary because it's NOT a char in the first place (without the cast.)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis You said “There is no built-in way to do that”. The OP never asked about making the literal have type `char`; they asked about assigning values from a literal to a `char`, which can be done.